# Why is it so HARD to have Windows 10 CMD console display Unicode correctly?

Tags: cmd.exe, fonts, unicode

Before showing the hard(difficult) example of Windows 10 (Win10.21H2 in this case), let me show an easy example by Ubuntu 22.04 .

I place file names with Chinese and Korean characters on a USB flash drive, plug it into Ubuntu and Windows and see how they are displayed.

Ubuntu 22.04 displays them very well.

[image: Ubuntu Terminal displays Unicode chars very well.]

```
$ la
total 196
drwxr-xr-x  5 chj  chj  32768 1970-01-01 08:00:00  ./
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root  4096 2022-06-09 00:43:35  ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 chj  chj  32768 2021-10-24 17:09:04  LEXAR-128G/
drwxr-xr-x  2 chj  chj  32768 2022-02-17 18:30:34  Raspi-wallpaper/
drwxr-xr-x  4 chj  chj  32768 2016-02-17 00:59:34 'System Volume Information'/
-rw-r--r--  1 chj  chj     23 2022-06-09 08:39:10  한국파일.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 chj  chj     17 2022-06-09 08:27:30  电脑文件.txt
```

But for Windows 10, I have to manually try many fonts(font family) until I find one that can display them well.

For an English version of Win10, the default CMD font is **Consolas**, then I try **Lucida Console**, **SimHei(黑体)**, and finally **NSimSun(新宋体)**.

Even though NSimSun display them correctly in this case, I'm still not sure whether NSimSun can cope with Unicode characters from other country/character-set (provided at least one font matching that country/character-set has been installed on the system).

Consolas:

[image: CMD with Consolas]

Lucida Console:

[image: CMD with Lucida Console]

SimHei:

[image: CMD with SimHei]

NSimSun:

[image: CMD with NSimSun]

It has been year 2022 now, I'm wondering why Microsoft makes it so hard for a user to view Unicode characters correctly and conveniently in CMD window. Is there any best practice on this?

Comment: It's probably part of the reason why Microsoft were pushing people away from CMD to the [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-gb&gl=GB) and Powershell. Backporting unicode into `cmd` is probably more effort than just getting a better and more modern terminal replacement.

Comment: Technically, the problem isn’t with `cmd` but the default Windows console emulator which has always sucked. It’s the very definition of _legacy_. `cmd` does this just fine – in Windows Terminal.

Comment: Try putting CMD in UTF-8 mode by entering the command `chcp 65001`.